# The most efficient way to change headers and footers on hundreds of MS Word documents

Tags: microsoft-word

I have hundreds of documents which I'd like to "customize" for a certain group by putting their name in the header and possibly also the footer of the document.  I'd like to do this for potentially dozens of groups.

Kind of like a mail merge, except instead of taking a single document and generating it hundreds of times with a different name each time (like the classic envelope example), I want to take hundreds of existing documents and generate a single copy of each with the name replaced in the header.

I'm not very familiar with using Fields in Word, but I'm wondering if I should be using a Field for this or is there a better way?

I'm using Office 365.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Word .docx documents are actually zip archives, which you can extract by renaming the document file ending to .zip. If you know programming, you could setup a script that renames, extracts and replaces the header in the .xml files contained inside. The header can be found in the `word/header1.xml` file.

I've done this before and it works surprisingly well for many kinds of repetitive tasks.